# How can I install additional dictionaries for Chrome?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, spell-check

I am running Chrome on Linux. How can I install different dictionaries (British English and Polish), so that I will get the fly-spell functionality in these languages?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I only found an option to add new languages after selecting "Advanced settings" and then clicking on Language in the top left "hamburger menu".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into Language settings and add desired language to list of languages for reading web sites (currently there is probably only English there). Once language is in that list, you will be able to use it for "fly-spell".